# Understanding memory allocation and a core dumped error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm a bit confused with memory allocation.

I want to fill a structure Sudoku with random number and then check if a box of 9 numbers are correct.

```
#define SUDOKU_SIZE 9 
typedef struct 
{ 
   int grid[SUDOKU_SIZE][SUDOKU_SIZE]; 
} sudoku_t;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof s);
    s->grid[0][0]=6;//manualy setting the value of the sudoku
    ...
    s->grid[8][8]=7;
    fill_sudoku_test(s);//fill s, a feasible Sudoku with random number
    int k, l;
    for(k=0;k<SUDOKU_SIZE;k+=3){
        for(l=0;l<SUDOKU_SIZE;l+=3){
            if(correct_box(s,k,l))//check if a box of 3 by 3 contains 9 differents numbers
                printf("Box correct at position :%d and %d\n",k,l);
         }
    }
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile this code, I got a core dumped error.

If somebody got a solution, I'm interested

**EDIT**

Here's the others functions :

```
void fill_sudoku_test(sudoku_t *s){
   int k, l;
   time_t t;
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));
   for(k=0;k<SUDOKU_SIZE;k++){
       for(l=0;l<SUDOKU_SIZE;l++){
           if(!(s->grid[k][l])) {
               s->grid[k][l]=rand()%SUDOKU_SIZE+1;
           }            
       }
   }
}


int correct_tab(int value[]){
   int i;
   int tab[9];
   for(i=0;i<SUDOKU_SIZE;i++){
      tab[i]=0;
   }
   for(i=0;i<SUDOKU_SIZE;i++){
      if(tab[value[i]-1]==1){
        return 0;
      }
      else{
        tab[value[i]-1]=1;
      }
   }
   return 1;
}

int correct_box(sudoku_t *s, int i, int j){
   int tab[SUDOKU_SIZE];
   int count=0;
   int k,l;
   for(k=0;k<3;k++){
      for(l=0;l<3;l++){
         tab[count]=s->grid[i+k][j+l];
      }
   }
   return (correct_tab(tab));
}
```

Comment: Are you probably missing the grid allocation? Post the `sudoku_t` structure. And `fill_sudoku_test` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof s);
```

should be

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof(sudoku_t));
```

or

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

**EDIT**

in function `correct_tab` the `value[i]` can be (and is) `0`. Then:

```
tab[value[i]-1]=1;
```

and

```
if(tab[value[i]-1]==1)
```

access the array out of bounds.

**EDIT 2**

In `correct_tab` `value` array is not intited for the whole `SUDOKU_SIZE` then some values of array are undefined.

You can, at least, declare it as:

```
int tab[SUDOKU_SIZE] = {0};
```

**EDIT3**

To answer to your comments:

Your init is correct: init numbers are between `1` to `9`.

The problem is that `correct_tab` is called from `correct_box` is passing `tab`, a local (stack allocated) array. This means 1 main thing:

- its values are not itited to 0. Those value are randoms due to the
  stack allocation.

using my EDIT2 code you can set 0 for all values of the array.

BTW your `correct_tab` function loops the whole tab array, where only some values are extracted from your `sudocu_t` struct matrix.
This happend due to:

1. `count` variable into `correct_box` function is always `0`. You must inc it each time you set a value into `tab` array.
2. You should pass the `count` value to `correct_tab` function to allow to loop on the real inserted values only.

Comment: As I commented: post other functions. Where is the core dump triggered?

Comment: Okay, I did it.
And the core dumped come after the fill_sudoku_test

Comment: Preserving the original style, the allocation could be written as `sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof *s);`

Comment: @LPs , I'm not agree because value[i] can only be numbers between 1 and 9 inclusive

Comment: Put a `printf("value[i] = %d\n", value[i]);` inside your loop and you will see...

Comment: Okay, I'm believing you... But I still don't understand, when I fill s, it only use number from 1 to 9. After that correct_box fill a tab with these numbers, and then, it use correct_tab(tab), why are there numbers like 0 or 4196074.. ?

Comment: Yeah, thank you a lot for your explanations... and your time!

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate:

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof s);
```

This only allocates memory sufficient to store a pointer. You probably mean:

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

Beyond that, you will need to use a debugger to identify which part of the code actually triggered the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

First problem lies in this line:

```
sudoku_t *s=malloc(sizeof s);
```

which means malloc is allocating memory equal to the size of pointer, which could be 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on the machine.

Ideally what u r expecting is allocating the size of structure, so this should be:

```
sudoku_t *s = (sudoku_t *) malloc(sizeof(sudoku_t));
```

Comment: [do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Normally as per the prototype of malloc, it returns a void pointer. So I think it's good to cast it to the structure type.

Comment: Take a look at the linked SO post. It gives you all infos.